# Remote mount point fails: Prevent unresponsive applications

Tags: mount

I need to mount a remote filesystem on Ubuntu 14.04 via sshfs or ncpmount (Novell). Currently I am calling ncpmount,

```
ncpmount -S SomeServ -A someserv.somewhere.net -V shareX -U username -t 200 /mnt/H
```

which correctly mounts the filesystem. From time to time the network seems to be unstable and the mount becomes unreachable. This causes a widespread freeze of desktop applications that, e.g., try to show a directory tree or directly access files on the mount point. The applications can only be shut down by a reboot or shutdown of the operating system.

I know that this issue is connected to the kernel waiting for IO to finish, a process that is not interruptible (e.g. via kill -9). My question is, since this issue is rather annoying:

**Is it possible to set up a remote mount point that recovers from failure, e.g., like a usb device?**

One thing I could imagine is to run a program that simulates an usb drive and mounts the filesystem. Of course this program will hang but the applications would survive...

**Edit:** I just found out that mounting via sshfs is not an option at my site.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if that helps but have you tried to mount it via sshfs yet? At least in my setup if the remotely mounted drive becomes unavailable, I don't experience any freezes whatsoever. I can't write to the remote drive and applications complain that the location they want to access is not available but that's really all that happens.

Comment: The site administrator told me today that it is not possible to mount the requested directories via sshfs. Thanks for the hint anyways.